# Creating and using a dummy NSData subclass doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I have a problem with creating my own subclass of `NSData`, which I want to have a custom `description` method. Even creating a dummy `NSData` subclass:

```
@interface MyData : NSData {}
@end
```

and

```
@implementation MyData
@end
```

and using it results in weird bugs (the function that uses it never exits, and control somehow returns to the run loop). I thought that maybe I am responsible for rewriting the designated initializers of `NSData` (calling the `super` implementation), but none is mentioned in the doc. So:

- what are the designated initializers of `NSData`?
- what is the bare minimum I need to write for a dummy subclass of `NSData`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Making an `NSData` subclass is difficult because (as [drewag noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772296/creating-and-using-a-dummy-nsdata-subclass-doesnt-work/5772458#5772458)) it is a member of a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH7-SW1). From the [Binary Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000717-CJBDBHCB):

> ...data objects are not actual instances of the NSData or NSMutableData classes but instead are instances of one of their private subclasses.

When you do `[[NSData alloc] initWith...]` you don't get back an `NSData`; you probably get back an `NSConcreteData`. The extraordinary Cocoa With Love has a [discussion and demonstration](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) of subclassing class clusters.

The best (and most idiomatic) option is probably [composition](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15): your custom class should simply contain an `NSData` ivar, and implement a description method that operates on that enclosed object.

While drewag's response is technically correct, this is a dangerous technique to use on Cocoa classes; it will override the `description` method of *every* `NSData` object in the program, whether you create it directly or not.

In the specific case of the `description` method this may be okay, but for another method more likely to be relied upon by other objects in the framework, it could cause large, hard-to-trace problems. You should only do this if you are sure that there is no other way.

It would be *far* better to create a category and method with a prefix:

```
@interface NSData (FX_Description) 
- (NSString *)FX_description;
@end
```

The Apple docs [specifically mention](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4) this category-override technique and advise against it:

> Because the methods declared in a category are added to an existing class, you need to be very careful about method names.
>
> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime.

An earlier version of the docs went on to say:

> The very presence of some category methods may cause behavior changes across all frameworks. For example, if you override the `windowWillClose:` delegate method in a category on `NSObject`, **all window delegates in your program then respond** using the category method; the behavior of all your instances of `NSWindow` may change. Categories you add on a framework class may cause mysterious changes in behavior and lead to crashes. [Emphasis mine.]

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to override a single function "description" consider using a "Category" instead:

```
@interface NSData (MyData)
-(NSString*)description;
@end

@implimentation NSData (MyData)
-(NSString*)description
{
    return @"something";
}
@end
```

Then, you can use this function on any instance of NSData.

It is very difficult to subclass NSData because it is a "Class Cluster." The public API treats it as one class, but in reality it is a collection of hidden subclasses. You can research overriding a class cluster, but it is almost never needed. Another option is to create your "MyData" class with NSData as a member variable instead of using a subclass.