# Obj-C subclass doesn't seem to recognize inherited selector

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass

First off, my code:

```
@interface Block : NSObject {
    NSData *data;
    NSInteger slice_count;
}

@property (readonly) NSData *data;

+ (Stopwatch *) runOldTestsUsingConfiguration:(TestConfiguration *)c;

- (Slice *) getSlice:(NSUInteger)idx;

@end

- (Slice *) getSlice:(NSUInteger)idx {
    void *b = (void*)[data bytes] + idx*slice_count;
    int len = [data length] / slice_count;
    Slice *ret = [Slice alloc];
    [ret initWithBytesNoCopy:b length:len freeWhenDone:NO];
    return ret;
    //NSString *temp2 = [data description];
    //NSRange r = NSMakeRange(idx*slice_count, [data length] / slice_count);
    //NSData *d = [data subdataWithRange:r];
    //NSString *temp = [d description];
    //Slice *s = [[Slice alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)[d bytes] length:r.length freeWhenDone:NO];
    //return s;
}
```

where `Slice` is a simple subclass of `NSData`.

For some reason I'm getting a run-time error that seems to indicate my Slice instance either a) isn't actually a concrete instance (?) or b) something is going wrong in its inheritance and the message isn't binding itself to Slice properly (almost certainly by my as yet unknown error).

The exact error I'm getting is this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
initialization method -initWithBytes:length:copy:freeWhenDone:bytesAreVM:
cannot be sent to an abstract object of class Slice: Create a concrete instance!'
```

Can anyone help me out? I've tried just about everything I can think of (basic routines of which are detailed in the message call itself) and I am still coming up dry. What does it mean when it says 'create a concrete instance'? Isn't that what I'm doing when I `alloc` it?

Comment: Splitting up an `alloc`/`init` is poor Cocoa style, (especially without re-assigning) and should never be done on any class that isn't yours (because you can't be sure that `init` won't throw away the object it's passed and return a new one).

Comment: See below; I wasn't concerned with style at that point. It's a debugging technique I've adopted over the years. I knew the dangers of doing so, but at that point there wasn't much else I could try that I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing NSData is a lot more complicated than you would think.  In most cases you are better off just writing a wrapper around NSData instead of a full subclass.

Comment: Why would writing a wrapper give me different results than writing a 'full subclass'? OO languages are usually pretty consistent about those things (at least ones that I'm really familiar with, of which I admit ObjC is not a member yet)

Comment: @vermiculus NSData may not be what you expect it do be under the hoods since it's a part of a class cluster. That is why subclassing it doesn't work as you expect it to do. If you wrap it then you aren't exposed the the implementation details of NSData. You can read more about it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5772610/608157)

Comment: @vermiculus The short version of it is that under the hood when you call `[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes...];` it returns a subclass that is considered a "concrete implementation" of `NSData`.  If you really want to do a full subclassing of `NSData` then you would need to implement several other methods for it to work the way you would expect.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, if I am only using public methods, why should it matter? I mean, I'm going to try this suggestion, but if it works I'll still be wondering why XD

Comment: @DanF, I noticed that... Maybe NSConcreteData doesn't have the methods I'm using (or something similarly problematic...) gotcha...

Comment: Although, I really am apprehensive about wrapping it just for a method  and variable. Would a category accomplish what I need it to do? (I think I can do away with the instance variable.)

Comment: @vermiculus Read [the answer that I linked to in my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5772610/608157). It explain why it matters.

Comment: @vermiculus I ran into a similar issue recently when trying to write a more serialization-friendly subclass of `NSMutableData`.  All I did was add a couple methods and a instance variable, but had to simply wrap it.  If all you want to do is add a couple new methods then a category should be just fine

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Very thorough answer on the subject, I even learned a bit!

Comment: @DanF, thanks for the resource - it seems that there are far more differences between Objective-C and other OO languages I've used that I had thought.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, init methods are allowed to re-assign self, and should therefore ALWAYS be used on the same line as alloc.

```
Slice *ret = [[Slice alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:b length:len freeWhenDone:NO];
```

I'm not sure if that's the root cause, but it's a red-flag to me that may lead you in a good direction.

EDIT:

Actually, it has me wondering if you have overridden +alloc in your subclass and aren't returning an instance...

Comment: This most likely is not the problem. Still, good to point out but it should be a comment.

Comment: `Slice` introduces exactly one instance variable and one method, which is not an inherited method. In times of desperation, I tend to tear apart expressions and go through them line by line :P Thanks, but I don't think this is the problem either. :P