# Custom class of type NSData misses -bytes

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, nsdata

I'm currently working on an iOS application (written in Swift), that should connect two (later more) iOS devices and transfer data between them using Bluetooth. The actual use should be music/audio distribution but right now i have enough problems sending a simple text message.

I use the Core Bluetooth Framework (Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy) to setup both peripheral and central roles and (after successfully establishing connection) i use this peripheral function to store my data in the appropriate characteristic, which can be read by the central:

```
func updateValue(Data, for: CBMutableCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: [CBCentral]?) -> Bool
```

I want to transfer data in a custom data type **"ChatMessage"** which contains one String variable to store the message text and one String to store the name of the sending device. The class is derived from the **NSData** type, therefore i also implemented the required init/encode/decode functions.

I thought there is no problem converting my **NSData** class to the type **Data** as the above-mentioned function requires. But at runtime i get this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -bytes only defined for abstract class.  Define -[MusicSync.ChatMessage bytes]!'
```

Is there a (getter?-) variable or a function i also have to implement in my custom class? If yes, how exactly should that look like? I'm pretty new in iOS developing, so i have no idea of what the bytes of a class are being used for.

Thanks in advance!

I am using XCode version 10.0, Swift 4 and for testing an iPhone XS Max with iOS 12.0.1 as well as an iPad Air 2 with iOS 12.0.

Comment: Subclassing NSData is difficult, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/5772296. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'd recommend to use an extension on your "ChatMessage" class that will generate the `(NS)Data` as you like and init with it too.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I changed the class type to "Codable" and used an JSONEncoder to encode my custom data type.